# Uploading pictures to Facebook using Graph API with Android SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a photo to facebook using graph api and keep getting OutOfMemory exception.
The code for the upload is this:

```
private void PostPhoto(SessionHandler facebook, Uri photoUri)
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    String realPath = getRealPathFromURI(photoUri); 
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(realPath);

    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

    params.putByteArray("picture", bos.toByteArray());


    try
    {
        facebook.mFacebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");            

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
    {

    } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException)
    {

    } catch (IOException ioException)
    {

    }

}
```

The exception raises on the decodeFile function and sometimes in the facebook SDK itself when it calls this line:

```
return Util.openUrl(url, httpMethod, parameters);
```

inside the request function.

The app is getting the picture content:// Uri by the ACTION_SEND intent.
getRealPathFromURI() is used to translate the content:// uri to a real sdcard path.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
byte[] data = null;
try {
    ContentResolver cr = mainActivity.getContentResolver();
    InputStream fis = cr.openInputStream(photoUri);
    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();              
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}     
Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");          
params.putByteArray("picture", data);
```

This is using the Rest API, the facebook sdk has the method for calling it so just change your request line from:

```
facebook.mFacebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");
```

to:

```
facebook.mFacebook.request(params);
```

and hopefully that will solve the problem.

Comment: looks like this code is not getting the out of memory exception. the code does reach the onComplete of the RequestListener, but the picture does not show in facebook. Tried to change the null in the request to "me/photos" and still nothing in the profile or albums.

Comment: @Idan - can you post the response your getting from facebook

Comment: response: Unsupported method, photos.upload

Comment: sorry this is using the legacy Rest API, see my edited answer for details on how to fix it. I'll try and figure out the graph API way to do it and let you know, but it might not be implemented yet!

Comment: By removing the method line the upload was successful but the pictures got in to a new album named after the app name. When getting in it using the web i get a message saying these pictures was uploaded using a different application and that i need to approve them.

Comment: You can add in the parameter "aid" as a string, i think this will set the album name, also add "uid" as an int which is the user id this might get around having to approve them (probably depends on the users privacy settings though)

Comment: added the params. did not helped. still asking me to approve the photos.

Comment: Ok SOLVED. has to add a publish_stream permission. to publish to an existing album i have to use aid/photos in the request path.

Comment: I presumed you already had that! Note to self - never presume anything! lol, glad you got it working. Can you mark the question as answered - ta.

Comment: I have done step by step but Facebook return the message":"Unsupported method, photos.upload.