# Android: openInputStream with URL throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

I'm trying to run the following code

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("URL of a photo");

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    try {
        InputStream fis = cr.openInputStream(uri);
        // Do some stuff here ..
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this throws a FileNotFoundException, and I'm sure the URL is correct. Is there another way to open input stream of a URL?

EDIT: LogCat output

```
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.vnvlvokc.com/ow_userfiles/plugins/shoppro/images/product_1.jpg
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:481)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:319)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at com.example.myfacebook.Act1.post_photo(Act1.java:68)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at com.example.myfacebook.Act1.onActivityResult(Act1.java:58)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2694)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2740)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:991)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-06 22:05:37.939: W/System.err(20057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3892)
11-06 22:05:37.949: W/System.err(20057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 22:05:37.949: W/System.err(20057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-06 22:05:37.949: W/System.err(20057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
11-06 22:05:37.949: W/System.err(20057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642)
11-06 22:05:37.949: W/System.err(20057):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm allowed to post external urls here, but this is the URL I'm testing on http://www.vnvlvokc.com/ow_userfiles/plugins/shoppro/images/product_1.jpg

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `InputStream` line with something like this `InputStream fis = (InputStream) new URL(fileUrl).getContent(); `

Comment: It produces IOException!

Comment: Can you share your LogCat with us? For verification purposes, you have the correct permission set in your manifest, right?

Comment: Asok, I don't think it's a permission problem. If it's, the logCat would suggest the right permissions for me. But anyway what's the permission for opening an input stream ? I'm not using any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to download the content of the picture to the phone, then you should not use an intent resolver but a HttpUrlConnection and copy its content to a file.

There are several ways to do that, few are corrects. If that's what you want to do tell me, I will give you some hints.

What you are doing with the content resolver is trying to get a ContentProvider from an app or from the system that could give you the content of this url.. it's really a bit awkward.

Comment: I'm following the accepted answer of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478572/uploading-pictures-to-facebook-using-graph-api-with-android-sdk

I want to upload a photo to a facebook album

Comment: And what's the link with what you are doing, both codes seem quite different

Comment: The first two lines inside the try is what I'm trying to do. I'm still at the very beginning :)

Comment: You need to start an intent to take a picture, then learn how to get the uri of the picture that will be returned. This is the uri you will then pass to a share intent to the facebook app.

Comment: And what if I want the image from a URL, not from my phone?

Comment: Why does this code produces FileNotFoundException anyway? I'm not keen on applying the steps in this link, I'm just learning and would like to know how to open an input stream for a URL

Comment: to open a stream you must use a HttpUrlConnection. The topic seems narrow, but it's actually quite vast when it comes to doing background things in the right way on Android. Look at the AsyncTask example here: http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/Android-URLImage.htm. When you want a more robust solution, have a look at RoboSpice on Github.

Comment: My pleasure. But have a look at this infographics to understand why RoboSpice is better :goo.gl/jxNin . Maybe for later though..